# MySQL order using varchar field

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a varchar field on which I wish to order records. Two of the possible contents of this field are "Applicant-Approved" and "Applicant-Declined". Both fields are of identical length and the first 10 characters are identical. Yet MySQL insists on sorting all the "Declined" records ahead of the "Accepted" records. Examined in hexadecimal, the "Accepted" field is clearly less than the "Declined" field. How can this be overcome?

Comment: Are you actually doing `select ... order by yourfield DESC`? if not, then look at `show create table tablename` and see what the default sort order(s) have been set to.

Comment: Please, add some code to the question as well as sample data in a tabular format

Comment: do you want to order by count of group ?? I mean if the applicant-approved is more in number it should come first like that?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why it is doing that but this should work.

```
 Order by AppField, right(left(AppFeild,11),1)
```